# [RF]: Using a variable while declaring a variable

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to create a variable using another variable using `Set Variable` Keyword. But I am getting below error.

```
${vname} = Set variable   var_
${{vname}a} = Set variable   a
Log ${var_a}
```

> Error: No keyword with name '${{vname}a}=' found.

Can someone help to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can't do what you are trying to do. What is the real problem you're trying to solve? There are likely better solutions than to try to create dynamic variable names.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with "set test variable" keyword:

```
${vname} = Set variable   var_
Set test variable   ${{vname}a}    a
Log ${var_a}
```